# Get notification from the papers in the conference and the calendar

Tags: research-process, conference

I work in the computer science field, and I would like to get notified when papers from conferences are available so that I don't have to be always looking to the conferences' webpage to see if they are available. Is there any service that do this?

My goal is just to find the latest CS papers to read. How people normally do? They are all the time looking for the conferences' webpage? They use google alerts?

I also would like to have a full calendar of the computer conferences that are available. Is there a webpage that shows this info?

Comment: Not all CS conferences offer their accepted papers in their web pages for download, since they are published e.g., by Springer, IEEE, ACM and so-on. Or are you asking about the announcement of the accepted papers?

Comment: I just want to get the latest CS papers to read. I am looking for an easier way to do it without having to look into the conferences webpages. I don't know if google alerts can help.

Comment: Yes, google alerts help. Follow your favorite authors and yourself (new papers AND citations) and when someone uploads a paper that cited them or you, you get an alert

Comment: That is two seperate questions. Please ask them in separate posts.